# Problems with Boost 1.55 on Mavericks

Tags: c++, boost, osx-mavericks

I upgraded my system to Mac OS 10.9 and spent the whole weekend to get my software working. Without many success though…

Some of the tools I need require boost, however I used boost 1.38 before, which simply does not compile on Mavericks. So I decide to use homebrew to install boost 1.55. The installation went without any problems, but when I try to compile my toolset, it throws me this error:

```
Syntax error /usr/local/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:343:
Error: void type variable can not be declared /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:243:
Error: void type variable can not be declared /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:245:
Error: Invalid type '>{typedef' in declaration of 'boost::exception_detail::error_info_base type;}' /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:78:
Error: class,struct,union or type element_type not defined  /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:439:
Internal error: global function template arg type /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:439:
Error: Invalid type '>{typedef' in declaration of 'void type;}' /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:127:
Internal warning: >{typedef void type;} comment can not set /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:127:
Error: Invalid type '>{typedef' in declaration of 'void type;}' /usr/local/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:152:
...
...
...
Warning: Error occurred during reading source files
Warning: Error occurred during dictionary source generation
Error: rootcint: error loading headers...
make[2]: *** [icetray/CMakeFiles/icetrayDict.cxx] Error 1
make[1]: *** [icetray/CMakeFiles/icetray.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not sure what's wrong and don't have a clue where to start to debug this. Google did not return anything helpful, so I'm really struggling right now.

The header files where installed correctly in /usr/local/Cellar and are linked to /usr/local/include.

Btw. I started with a completely fresh Mavericks install (+ Xcode for the devtools) and only used brew to install some additional packages.

**This is the quoted code in `exception.hpp`:**

```
340: struct large_size { char c[256]; };
341: large_size dispatch_boost_exception( exception const * );

343: struct small_size { };
344: small_size dispatch_boost_exception( void const * );
```

**And the corresponding code from the first Error, in `smpart_ptr`:**

```
239: #if !defined( BOOST_NO_SFINAE ) && !defined( BOOST_NO_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION ) && !defined( BOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR )

241: // rvalue auto_ptr support based on a technique by Dave Abrahams

243: template< class T, class R > struct sp_enable_if_auto_ptr
244: {
245: };

247: template< class T, class R > struct sp_enable_if_auto_ptr< std::auto_ptr< T >, R >
248: {
249:     typedef R type;
250: }; 

252: #endif
```

**Compiler flags:**

```
C_FLAGS = -Wall  -Wno-mismatched-tags -Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unused
-Wunneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-parantheses-equality   -g -fPIC -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/cmake/tool-patches/common
-I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/public -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/private -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/include/boost -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/i3/seaports/include/log4cplus-1.0.2 -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/i3/seaports/root-v5.34.12/include/root    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -include /Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/build_debug/CMakeFiles/I3.h

C_DEFINES = -DI3_USE_CINT -DI3_USE_ROOT -DPROJECT=icetray
-D_REEENTRANT

CXX_FLAGS = -Wall -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-mismatched-tags
-Wno-char-subscripts -Wno-unused -Wunneeded-internal-declaration -Wno-parantheses-equality   -g -fPIC -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/cmake/tool-patches/common
-I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/public -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/private -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/include/boost -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/i3/seaports/include/log4cplus-1.0.2 -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/i3/seaports/root-v5.34.12/include/root    -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -include /Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/build_debug/CMakeFiles/I3.h

CXX_DEFINES = -DI3_USE_CINT -DI3_USE_ROOT -DPROJECT=icetray
-D_REEENTRANT
```

**rootcint build command:**

```
cd /Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/build_debug/icetray && \
    ../env-shell.sh rootcint -f \
    /Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/build_debug/icetray/CMakeFiles/icetrayDict.cxx -c -DI3_USE_ROOT -DI3_USE_CINT \
    -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/cmake/tool-patches/common \
    -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/public \
    -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/private \
    -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.55.0/include/boost \
    -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers \
    -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/i3/seaports/include/log4cplus-1.0.2 \
    -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/i3/seaports/root-v5.34.12/include/root \
    -I/Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/public \
    -p /Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/build_debug/CMakeFiles/I3.h \
    /Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/public/icetray/I3FrameObject.h \
    /Users/tamasgal/Xapps/seatray/searecsim/trunk/src/icetray/LinkDef.h
```

**Relevant code part from `I3.h`:**

```
#define BOOST_NO_WREGEX

#ifdef I3_OPTIMIZE
#define BOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS
#endif

#include <boost/version.hpp>


#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
using boost::shared_ptr;
using boost::dynamic_pointer_cast;

// workaround for braindead rootcint.  doesn't recognize the using
// boost::shared_ptr.  I can just see this popping up to cause us
// unspeakable aggravation in the future...

#ifdef __CINT__
template <typename T>
struct shared_ptr : boost::shared_ptr<T> { };
```

Comment: What are you  compiling with, flags etc.?

Comment: The whole project is using `cmake`, I have to figure out where those parameters are stored.

Comment: @bamboon Got them, please have a look the updated question!

Comment: Please edit your question to include code showing where you `#include` these headers. It would also be helpful to see how everything is compiled, the `CXXFLAGS` are nice but not enough.

Comment: @SamMiller Alright, I added some more code snippets. Unfortunately it is a quite big software framework, so it isn't that easy to provide a quick overview… I'm a bit curious about that comment on the shared pointer workaround :-\

Comment: Use macports to install boost, way easier

Comment: @aaronman that does not solve my problem. And how would be something easier than "brew install boost"? On the other hand, I'll never use MacPorts again, it messed up my whole system several times in the past…